# Error in Upgrading Magento

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, error

When I Was Upgrading Magento 1.8.1.0 to Magento 2.4 I had Got This Error Please Guide Me.

[image][martarab@inpro3 public_html]$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache types config flushed successfully
Connectiondefault" is not defined

In ResourceConnection.php line 148:

Connectiondefault" is not defined

Comment: Check that you have an **env.php** file in your `app/etc` folder and that your DB details are defined correctly.

Comment: yes i have env.php and db details are defined in it

Answer (score 0):

Please check env.php file in app / etc directory. If not, copy it from another project. If it already exists change the line 'connection' => 'default' to 'connection' => 'production' or 'connection' => 'developer'